# between two semiprimes differing by 4 there are two primes

Tags: prime-numbers, semiprimes

The two semiprimes 58 and 62 differ by four and have two primes 59 and 61 in the interval.  Do you think this happens an endless number of times?

Comment: what is a semiprime?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner A product of two primes.

Comment: No. Between $15898, 15902$ there is only $15901$

Comment: (10,14),(58,62),(1318,1322),(1618,1622),(4258,4262),(5098,5102),(6658,6662),(6778,6782),(11698,11702),(12538,12542),(21058,21062),(66358,66362),(83218,83222),(88258,88262),(107098,107102),(110878,110882),(114658,114662),(127678,127682),(130198,130202),(140758,140762),(141958,141962),(144538,144542),(148198,148202),(149518,149522),(157558,157562),(161338,161342),(163858,163862),(175078,175082),(186478,186482),(204598,204602),(230938,230942),(249538,249542),(267958,267962),(273898,273902),(312838,312842),(322918,322922),(336898,336902),(367018,367022),(369658,369662),(393538,393542)

Comment: Longer list with full program [here](https://tio.run/##pY@xDoMgFEVn@IoXEhNUGqtuTVz7Bd2MgwnYYioStEO/ngKa0qRLk7Ldy3nvgH6ut1nV1ipooDxuB2sjJ7G4pr2Yh@gyqvIyxcNsQINUYHp1FbRivj1hJAfYBlrduYg8N0ZOZ9qTTHsWoR0dO7f@3N8XgRcxyWgM3b9KFsaLYndGfAw4QtHZ6iy8xf8Uw09G6BV/p7za8ufGQ/nd5XVQu6hWSmjCWcJTklAHM3eZMqF4QxhJrX0B)

Comment: Kenny LAU should submit this to OEIS.

Comment: Note that if $p, p+2$ are primes you are looking for $p-1, p+3$ to be semiprimes. These will necessarily have the factor $2$ and can't have the factor $4$. For all but the lowest primes neither can be divisible by $3$ (they differ by $3$ from a large prime) or by $5$ (because $2$ and $5$ are two primes already - there is just one case where $p-1=10$). Hence $p+1$ is divisible by $60$. There are eventual constraints for other "small" primes - e.g. either $p+1$ is divisible by $7$ or none of the five numbers is so that $p\equiv 2,3,6 \bmod 7$

Comment: You should look at question #2469395.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is open because [we don't even know if there are infinitely many twin primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPrimeConjecture.html).

However, [a result of Landau](https://mathoverflow.net/q/35927) is that the density of semiprimes is $\dfrac{\log x}{x \log \log x}$ while the density of primes is $\dfrac{\log x}x$. Therefore, a crude approximation of the density of the value required is $\dfrac{(\log x)^4}{x^4 (\log \log x)^2}$.

---

I've written a program to generate such pairs:

```
n = 10000000
primes = [True]*(n+1)
for p in range(2,n+1):
    if primes[p]:
        for j in range(p*p,n+1,p):
            primes[j] = False
semiprimes = [False]*(n+1)
for p in range(2,n+1):
    if primes[p]:
        for j in range(p,(n+1)//p):
            if primes[j]:
                semiprimes[p*j] = True

for p in range(2,n+1):
    if primes[p] and primes[p+2] and semiprimes[p-1] and semiprimes[p+3]:
        print("(%d,%d)"%(p-1,p+3),end=",")
```